# How to obtain accountId from google api?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I've been playing around with google analytics api.
At this moment I know how to get the `access_token` but don't know how to obtain `accountId`

Is there a specific endpoint that provides accountId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to list all account ids available to a user, you probably need to use the Google Analytics Management API
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accounts/list

If you are using GA4, then the Google Analytics Admin API is a preferable option:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/accounts/list

Comment: Oh, I tried that but wasn't attentive enough and got confused by multiple accounts in there.